# BotFramework Composer, getting 404 error on callback at the skill

Tags: python, botframework, chatbot, bot-framework-composer

## Steps To Reproduce:

### Step 1:

Create a bot using composer(v1.0.0 installed form DMG on mac), choosing Echo Bot template.

### Step 2:

Clone echo skill sample from the current repo:
https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot

### Step 3:

Run the skill locally.

### Step 4:

#### Connect to skill:

[image]

The endpoint in the picture is with port 3980 but it sue to at the last attempts the main bot was served by the composer on current bot. The point is that I set the callback URL to be the URL on which the main bot is running.

### Step 5:

Add skill to Unknown Intent Dialog, After the echo response:
[image]

## The Error:

I relieve an error at the skill side. After debugging of the skill I found that the problem is at the callback which returns 404 error back to the skill on sending activity.

```
uring handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/victorvasiliev/PycharmProjects/BotBuilder-Samples/samples/python/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot/echo-skill-bot/adapter_with_error_handler.py", line 71, in _send_eoc_to_parent
    await turn_context.send_activity(end_of_conversation)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 170, in send_activity
    result = await self.send_activities([activity_or_text])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 217, in send_activities
    return await self._emit(self._on_send_activities, output, logic())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 295, in _emit
    return await logic
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/turn_context.py", line 212, in logic
    responses = await self.adapter.send_activities(self, output)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 686, in send_activities
    raise error
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botbuilder/core/bot_framework_adapter.py", line 672, in send_activities
    activity.conversation.id, activity.reply_to_id, activity
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botframework/connector/aio/operations_async/_conversations_operations_async.py", line 533, in reply_to_activity
    raise models.ErrorResponseException(self._deserialize, response)
botbuilder.schema._models_py3.ErrorResponseException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'Not Found'
```

Did anybody faced the same issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please have a look at the handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: We will need some more context in order to answer your question. Please link to any tutorials you are following to help us reproduce the problem. What skill are you using? Where are you seeing that exception? Are you using the Emulator or some other channel? Are you using [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/python/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot)? How are you integrating an ordinary non-adaptive bot sample with the [Bot Framework Composer](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer)?

Comment: Yes I'm using the sample, I run it locally. Also I do succeed confecting the skill outside of the composer. But I have the error using the Composer. I get the exception at the skill side. It failed sending the activity back to the main bot. This is the URL that generated on sending the activity back: 
'http://localhost:3979/api/v3/conversations/<uuid>/activities/<uuid>' - The skill receives 404 on that.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I use the emulator. The main bot also run locally. I run it using "Test in emulator" button at the composer.

Comment: But what does the Composer have to do with anything? How are you loading that non-Composer sample into the Composer, and why? Can you edit the question to include more screenshots of your process? Please familiarize yourself with the Composer docs to understand what it's about: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/introduction

Comment: I updated the question with detailed steps of how to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-connect-to-a-skill#configure-settings-in-composer) that your skill host endpoint needs to end with `api/skills` and not just `api`:

> Select **Skills** from the Composer menu. In the **Skills** page, if your skill is remote, enter `<ngrok address>/api/skills` in the **Skill Host Endpoint** field. If your skill is local, you should enter `localhost:port/api/skills` in the **Skill Host Endpoint** field.

The skill host endpoint is used as the service URL in activities sent to the skill, which means it will be the base URI for any Conversations API methods the skill calls. If your skill tries to send requests to a non-existent URL then you should expect to get 404's. The Composer bot will be routing requests to routes starting with `api/skills` so that's what you should be putting in your service URL.